# Why pageProps in NextJS page component is not being passed?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have `index.js` page where I use `getServerSideProps()` to fetch Strapi data via graphql. For some reason the `props` object is coming empty. I have properly configured `_app.js` and I definitely return value with SSR.

`index.js`

```
const IndexPage = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props) // logs empty object {}
  }, [props])

return (
    <>
     ...
    </>
}

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  return {
    props: {
      data: ["Hello World!"]
    }
  }
}
```

`_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps, router }) {
  console.log(pageProps) // this logs { data: ['Hello World] } object

  return (
    <AppProvider>
      <AnimatePresence
        initial={false}
        onExitComplete={() => window.scrollTo({ top: 0 })}
        mode="wait"
      >
        <Component {...pageProps} key={router.route} />
      </AnimatePresence>
    </AppProvider>
  )
}
```

So, am I doing something wrong or is it a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. I completely overlooked the fact I use custom HOC for page transition animations:

```js
export default withTransition(IndexPage)
```

It didn't pass parent component's props down.

```js
export const withTransition = ParentComponent => {
  ...

  return () => (
    <>
      <ParentComponent />
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```

FIX:

```js
export const withTransition = ParentComponent => {
  ...

  return (props) => (
    <>
      <ParentComponent {...props} />
      ...
    </>
  )
}
```